# Node.js + Express get two queries into one JSON Object

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

i'm new to Node.js and Express and managed to have a simple API that fetches data from a mysql DB.
So far so good. Simple requests are no problem. But for the following example i need some help.
I tried a couple things but the don't work out at all. So i don't have any code because it's not working at all. I use mysql2 to connect to the database.

So i have basically two tables. The first one contains matchdays. The other one contains matchday_scores.
So what i need to get is a JSON File that is structured as the following:

```
[
 {
   "matchdayid": 1,
   "matchdaydate": "2023.02.12",
   "scores":
          [{
            "name": "Ed",
            "legs_won": 3,
            "average": 47,8},
          {
            "name": "Nick",
            "legs_won": 2,
            "average": 42,1}],
  },
  {
   "matchdayid": 2,
   "matchdaydate": "2023.02.19",
   "scores":
          [{
            "name": "Ed",
            "legs_won": 3,
            "average": 47,8},
           {
            "name": "Nick",
            "legs_won": 2,
            "average": 42,1}],
  },
 ....
```

Is this anyhow possible?

Either i use the matchdayid to build a new query or i get this sorted out in one Query. But for both i dont really have any more clues how to get there.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need two queries. Use one query with a `JOIN` to combine the two tables. Then construct the nested arrays and objects when you loop over the results.

Comment: Start with: `SELECT * FROM matchday m JOIN matchday_scores s ON m.matchdayid = s.matchdayid ORDER BY m.matchdayid`

Comment: Hey @Barmar thanks for the reply. I do know how to join tables etc. I already use them to get the names for the player ids etc. but my problem is that I need a nested json object but don’t have a clue how to get there. Maybe my coding skills are insufficient. A simple json is no problem, the nested json breaks my mind

Comment: I already tried to loop over the first array that I get an insert the scores with splice(). But in this case I have two problems. 1. I’m missing the declaration like „scores“ in the json itself. 2. after the first splice I don’t get the matchday id since the index is not on the same position it used to be

Answer (score 0):

Join the two tables by `matchdayid`. Then loop through the results, creating the nested arrays and objects. Whenever the `matchdayid` changes, start a new object in the result array, and push the scores onto its `scores` array.

```js
db.query(`SELECT m.matchdayid, m.matchdaydate, s.name, s.legs_won, s.average
        FROM matchday AS m
        JOIN matchday_scores AS s ON m.matchdayid = s.matchdayid
        ORDER BY m.matchdayid`, function(res, err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }
  let results = [];
  let lastid = null;
  let curscore;
  res.forEach(({
    matchdayid,
    matchdaydate,
    name,
    legs_won,
    average
  }) => {
    if (matchdayid !== lastid) {
      curscore = {
        matchdayid,
        matchdaydate,
        scores: []);
      results.push(curscore);
    }
    curscore.scores.push({
      name,
      legs_won,
      average
    });
  });
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I needed to tweak the code a little bit.  Still i get TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable. I try to figure it out. I think i got the idea. I tried to get two arrays into one instead of getting one array and grooming it down to my needs, i will try further.